# Using external react component missing react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

Imagine i have large reactjs project lets call it `A` and i want to use external component residing in another project which consist only of pure components (`.jsx & .css`  files) without `node_modules` folder lets call that project `B`. 
Problem component from project `B` cannot find react.

`Module build failed: Error: Couldn't find preset "react" relative to directory`

Logically because there is no node_modules folder in project.

Is there a way to instruct components from project `B` to use node_modules from project `A`

I was thinkning somehow utilize webpack but no idea how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a root folder that contains a node_modules folder that will be shared to all your sub-projects (A and B). Inside this folder you can drop all the "common" components, modules, libraries, etc.

When you require a module, NodeJS will look for the node_modules folder on that project, if doesn't find the module there, it will look for it in a directory above and so long.